# Channels Array didn't work in PubNub

Tags: node.js, publish-subscribe, pubnub

I tried to create a array list with some channels but I didn't received the subscribed messages. Sample code:

```
var channels_list = [ 'channel1','channel2','channel3' ]; 
pubnub.subscribe({
    channels: channels_list
});
```

If I change the code for this I can receive the messages

```
pubnub.subscribe({
    channels: [ 'channel1','channel2','channel3' ]
});
```

Why the first option doesn't work? What I'm doing wrong?

This is my nodejs script

```
var PubNub = require('pubnub');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var url_mongo = "mongodb://localhost/database";
var db;
var channels_list = [];

MongoClient.connect(url_mongo, function(err, _db) {
    if (err) console.log("Error: ", err);
    console.log("Connected to mongodb");
    db = _db;
    init();
});

function init() {
    pubnub = new PubNub({
        subscribeKey : '...',
        logVerbosity:true
    });

    getAllChannels();

    pubnub.addListener({
        status: function(event) {
            console.log("status: " + JSON.stringify(event));
        },
        message: function(event) {
            console.log("message: " + JSON.stringify(event));
        },
        presence: function(event) {
            console.log("presence: " + JSON.stringify(event));
        }
    });

    pubnub.subscribe({
        channels  : channels_list
    });

    function getAllChannels() {
        db.collection("channels").find({}).toArray(function(err, docs){
            if(err) console.log(err);
            else{
                channels_list = [];

                for(i = 0; i != docs.length; i++){
                    channels_list.push('channel-'+docs[i]._id);
                }

                console.log(channels_list);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The connection to MongoDB is correct and the channels_list have channels. I verify this part

Regards,

Comment: in terms of JavaScript those are the same!  They should be the same.

Comment: looks right both ways! - https://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/api-reference-sdk-v4#subscribe_example

Comment: Both ways work for me. Can you provide full script that reproduces your issue. What version of the PubNub Node SDK are you using?

Comment: I post like a new Answer

Comment: The Stack Overflow protocol is to add the code to your original question (Edit) unless your code is *the answer*.

Comment: Done. Can you see now the update answer?

Comment: Can you add `logVerbosity:true` to your init of PubNub and send us the output? I updated your code above with this parameter. I also modified your listener code to provide cleaner output.

Comment: I add `logVerbosity:true` and modified the listener too and the output is the same.

`Connected to mongodb
Subscribing Turbines...
[ 'channel-1-data', 'channel-2-data', 'channel-3-data' ]`